# Employer Letter for NRI Home Loan

Tags: india, loans, home-loan

Please advise: for an NRI working in US applying for home loan in India,  Bank is asking for employer letter, latest salary revision letter from employer and employer ID card etc.. but if NRI is an independent consultant, how do we produce these docs, where there is not an employer but only clients. Please help advise on this subject, can applicant self 
adress these letter/ docs etc...thanks

Answer (score 1):

The documents asked are the standard documents requested for approving home loan.

Inform the Bank of your status as NRI. It would help if you show your NRE/NRO accounts and funds in them. Quite a few Banks go all the way to give a loan to NRI as they consider that repayments is less risky than someone in Indian salary.

Also showing them the US Bank Account statement for a period of year or so will also help you get the loan.

Comment: Thanks for the advise, could you suggest some examples of such  banks that like you have mentioned that will provide loans for NRI more readily. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Go to any large Public Sector Bank or Large Private Banks, they have special NRI cell and red carpet waiting :)

Comment: I am having H DFC , AXIS, ICICI, AN

Comment: And SBI in order listed Hope I am on right track of choice - greatly appreciate ur comments thanks

Comment: Yep anyone of these should welcome you. Good Luck :)